# rnn sequence retrieval with tensorflow or cntk

Tags: python, tensorflow, cntk

Having a list of constant length sequences(array of 192 int), I want to retrieve the nearest complete sequence matching partial input :
Example with 4 sequences :

```
1,4,3,2  
1,2,3,4  
1,2,3,4  
1,2,1,4
```

input -> 1,2 output ->1,2,3,4
Is `seq2seq` model the best way to solve this ?
Where can I find a COMPLETE example with tensoflow or CNTK (model creation, training, decode) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a seq2seq tutorial here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_204_Sequence_To_Sequence.ipynb